# How do I combine these 2 regex patterns into one using logical AND?

Tags: regex

I have 2 regexes: `[CD]\d\d(\.\d(\d)?)?` and `(?!C7[789])`

I want to accept `D77`, `D78`, `D79` but NOT `C77`, `C78`, `C79`.

Thank you.

Comment: Place `(?!C7[789])` before `[CD]\d\d(?:\.\d\d?)?`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/EGH68V/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this worked:
`(?!C7[789])[CD]\d\d(.\d(\d)?)?`

Thanks [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)